# Error While launching Appium- Unhandled error:Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory

Tags: appium

I am using Appium 1.3.7. on windows .it was working properly few days back but today when i accessed it it gave me error

`Unhandled error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory`.

I googled it and came to know that this may be because of environmental variables. but i have set `ANDROID_HOME` and `PATH` correctly. I also upgraded it 1.4.0. but still the same error.

Logs:

```
Starting Node Server
info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.7 (REV 72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","noReset":true,"logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"18","automationName":"Appium"}
info: Console LogLevel: debug
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platform":"Android","deviceName":"Android","platformName":"Android","appActivity":"com.android.mms.ui.ConversationComposer","appPackage":"com.android.mms","version":""}}
info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.2 (java 1.5)
info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : platform, version
info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 21b1fc22-a8bc-4ae7-8969-d0d5b101dbe0
info: Starting android appium
info: [debug] Getting Java version
info: Java version is: 1.8.0_40
info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
error: Unhandled error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\android-sdks;\build-tools'
at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:654:18)
at exports.getDirectories (C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\helpers.js:100:18)
at ADB.checkSdkBinaryPresent (C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:97:25)
at ADB.checkAdbPresent (C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:134:8)
at Function.ADB.createADB (C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:73:7)
at androidCommon.initAdb (C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:1059:9)
at C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:610:21
at C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:249:17
at iterate (C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:149:13)
at C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:160:25 context: [POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platform":"Android","deviceName":"Android","platformName":"Android","appActivity":"com.android.mms.ui.ConversationComposer","appPackage":"com.android.mms","version":""}}]
```

Comment: correct way of setting ANDROID_HOME & related folder paths under it

https://gist.github.com/patrickhammond/4ddbe49a67e5eb1b9c03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in the path `D:\android-sdks;\build-tools` you have change it to

```
D:\android-sdks\build-tools
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene..i changed android_home environment variable. Before it was "D:'android-sdks;". The ";" at the end created issue. Now i chaged it to "D:\android-sdks" ..i.e. removed ";" at the end.